# Java add 000 to end of int

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a load of zeros to the end of an int.

I have a for loop that passes `i` to a method.

So when i is passed to the method I want to say `i+000` to `i+999`

I've tried

```
int i = 1;
int j = 000;
int k = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j));
System.out.println(k);
```

But this just prints out `10`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use `int k = i * 1000`?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify why your attempt doesn't work. It's because `int j = 000;` will jut set the int to `0`, this will naturally become the string `"0"` which is why you get `"10"` when you add the two strings together.

To offer a modification to your attempt (though I would go with Petter's solution personally), you can just use a fixed string:

```
int i = 1;
String j = "000";
int k = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i) + j);
System.out.println(k);
```